# Overlapping with Serial0/0/0

Tags: cisco, ping, interface

I have tried configuring the serial interfaces and it is working for two devices which is my HQ1 and HQ2:

- HQ1 - IP address `120.244.121.136` on `Serial0/0/0`
- HQ2 - IP address `120.244.121.139` on `Serial0/0/0`

The above two do ping, however, when I do the bottom two, they are not pinging, and I am getting an error regarding overlaps with `serial0/0/0`:

- RM1 - IP address `120.244.121.140` on `Serial0/0/0`
- HQ1 - IP address `120.244.121.143` on `Serial0/1/1`

Each has a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0`.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Which router model and configurations? What other information do you have that we could use? Routers route between networks, not the same network.

Comment: @RonMaupin 1941 version of routers and all of the above are routers.

Comment: Unless those are /32's (255.255.255.255, single addresses), 139 and 140 are the same network.

Comment: The error about overlapping networks happens when you try to configure two router interfaces in one router with the same network. That is why the configurations are useful. Routers route between networks, not on the same network, which is what you seem to want to do.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that, on the HQ1 router, you are attempting to put the same network on multiple routed interfaces. I think you mean these serial interfaces to be for point-to-point links. You should use a network (`/31` or, if you are more traditional, `/30`) for your point-to-point links. You would then have two usable addresses for the links, and one of the two addresses goes on one end of the link, and the other address goes on the other end of the link.

Alternatively, you could use any other network size, but you need to use separate networks on the two interfaces in the same router.

Routers route between networks; they don't route from one network to the same network. How will the routing table know to which of the two interfaces in the same network it should forward packets for that network?